# I can't seem to use any of Sverchok's mesh filter tools. Did something change in Blender 2.8?

Tags: sverchok

With reference to the tutorial at: https://sverchok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes/analyzers/mesh_filter.html, none of the examples shown appear to work in Blender 2.8.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are doing and how your layout looks like, but node tree checcked now:
[image: Yes we can]

Comment: Thanks - that works for me too (and produces some very nice results) - but I still can't reproduce all the examples shown at the link provided in my question.